# Configure git to always show absolute paths

Tags: git, path, usability

How to configure git to always show absolute paths?

Example for `git status -uno`:

Actual behavior (relevant paths):

```
    new file:   xxx/xxx.c
```

Wanted behavior (absolute paths):

```
    new file:   /home/zzz/xxx/xxx.c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can get `git status` to show absolute paths, but you can configure it to show paths relative to the git root, see `man git-status` for details:

> If the config variable `status.relativePaths` is set to `false`, then all paths shown are relative to the repository root, not to the current directory.

```
~repo/src $ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    a.txt
```

And

```
~repo/src $ git config --global status.relativePaths false
```

```
~repo/src $ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    src/a.txt
```

Comment: Will the `show absolute paths` feature be useful in `git`?